# Trim sequences based on alignment

Tags: python, regex, numpy, bioinformatics, biopython

I'm trying to edit an MSA (Multiple Sequence Alignment) file generated by ClustalW, to trim sequences before the consensus one, using BioPython. 
*xxx refers to other bases not relevant here*

Here's the example I/O :

INPUT

```
ITS_primer_fw               --------------------------------CGCGTCCACTMTCCAGTT
RBL67ITS_full_sequence      CCACCCCAACAAGGGCGGCCACGCGGTCCGCTCGCGTCCACTCTCCAGTTxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PRL2010                     ACACCCCCGAAAGGGCGTCC------CCTGCTCGCGTCCACTATCCAGTTxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
BBF32_3                     ACACACCCACAAGGGCGAGCAGGCG----GCTCGCGTCCACTATCCAGTTxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
BBFCG32                     CAACACCACACCGGGCGAGCGGG-------CTCGCGTCCACTGTCGAGTTxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
ITS_primer_fw               CGCGTCCACTMTCCAGTT
RBL67ITS_full_sequence      CGCGTCCACTCTCCAGTTxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PRL2010                     CGCGTCCACTATCCAGTTxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
BBF32_3                     CGCGTCCACTATCCAGTTxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
BBFCG32                     CGCGTCCACTGTCGAGTTxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The documented code for `AlignIO` describes just a way to extract sequences by treating the alignment as an *array*. In this example

```
align = AlignIO.read(input_file, "clustal")
sub_alignment = align[:,20:]
```

I was able to extract a subalignment made by all the sequences (:) starting from the 20th nucleotide. I'm looking for a way to replace the `20` in the example with the position of the first nucleotide of the consensus sequence.

Comment: Added regex tag, maybe as an alternative solution to biopython.

Comment: Is the input file always 3 rows?

Comment: Input file has multiple rows, here's reported three just as an example. How could this be done with regex? I'm studying python so I'm not really fluent currently with.

Comment: I don't know python, thought this could be done using regex. I could have a go if you add more example rows using R?

Comment: I see, so we want to match the 1st row to other rows, and substring.

Comment: I've added two other lines to I/O. Using R will not be the preferred way to do it, because I'm running it inside a python 3.x console where R is not used. That's the reason why I'm not doing this with bash text manipulation possibilities like awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer thanks to a Biostars user.

The twitch is looking into column to find the start point, which will be as expected after the last '-'. By default into my alignment first row is the shortest, and starts with '-' before the alignment get good.

So here's the code:

```
aln = AlignIO.read(input_file, "clustal")
for col in range(aln.get_alignment_length()):  # search into column
    res = list(aln[:,col])
    if not '-' in res:
        position = col                         # find start point
        print('First full column is {}'.format(col))
        break
print(aln[:,position::])                       # print the whole alignment starting from the position variable found
```

Comment: I found your answer very useful!
Here's the code to reverse the alignment so you can trim the other end too.
```def reverse_ma(aln):
        for i in range(len(aln)):
             aln._records[i].seq = aln._records[i].seq[::-1]
        return aln
```